# Canvas returns blank URI when drawn to from a video with a blob source - Javascript

Tags: javascript, canvas, blob

I'm developing an extension that gets thumbnails from videos and have run into a problem that I when I call `drawImage` on a canvas using a video with a `blob:` source, the image drawn is completely transparent. Below is the code used in the content script:

```
        video.addEventListener("seeked", () => {
            let canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
            canvas.width = 160;
            canvas.height = 90;
            canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(video, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
            console.log(canvas.toDataURL());
            chrome.storage.local.set({[imageKey]: canvas.toDataURL()},()=>console.log("saved"));
        });
        video.currentTime = 10;
```

The video element has been loaded and this method works on elements without a source including `blob`. Any advice or tips on how to get the actual image would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can't repro from a normal context... https://jsfiddle.net/me7fon09/

Comment: I can only produce the problem in practice. When using J-Fiddle it works fine, but when using Disney+ or another streaming service I can only get blank images. Even with code as simple as this 
`const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');

const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

let GetVideoImage = (video, imageKey)=> {

 video.addEventListener('canplay', () => {

  ctx.drawImage(video, 0, 0);

  console.log(canvas.toDataURL());
 });

}`

Comment: ah... from a Disney+ video? They probably have DRMs which will indeed blocks you from scraping their content.

Comment: Are there partial methods of getting around them? I understand the need for the DRM's but I'm still hopeful I can find a creative way to scrape a thumbnail